# Principled Volume not showing in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have a principled volume node attached to a cube, to create a bit of "fog" for my small scene. It shows in the viewport, but is absent in the render. For my cube, I don't have anything connected to the surface node - only the volume. Do I have to enable any extra passes or anything? Any ideas?

[image]

Thanks! :)

Viewport:
[image]

Render:
[image]

Comment: weird because if you create another cube and give it the exact same material it will work fine, so it has to do with the cube itself

Comment: Oh whoa.. how strange... On my initial cube, I also had a particle system for my little dust particles... It seems to work without the particle system, so at least I've got that to work off of... Hm..

Comment: the particle system doesn't seem to be the problem....